# Can I create an AbstractBaseUser like this?

Tags: python, django, django-models

class Staff(AbstractBaseUser):

```
email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
username = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)
date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Date Joined", auto_now_add=True)
last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Last Login", auto_now_add=True)
is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
position = models.CharField(max_length=45)
department_fk = models.ForeignKey(
    Department, models.CASCADE, db_column='department_fk')  <----- This is what im worried about
```

I dont know if it will accept a foreign key in django.

Can anyone give me an advice how to properly do this?

It creates the migrations and lets me migrate it but when I create a super user, it gives me this error

```
mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'app_staff.id' in 'field list'")
```

**I got the answer for my problem, if anyone has the same problem kindly message me or comment on this post**

Comment: it will accept anything on this attribute. please see the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#db-column

Comment: Hi @ruddra, What do you mean by that?